# Elasticsearch autocomplete integer field

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, prefix

I am trying to implement an autocomplete feature on a numeric field (it's actual type in ES is `long`).

I am using a jQuery UI Autocomplete widget on the client side, having it's `source` function send a query to Elasticsearch with the prefix term to get a number (say, 5) of autocomplete options.

The query I am using is something like the following:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "myField": "<term>"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "myAggregation": {
            "terms": { 
                "field": "myField",
                "size": 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Such that if `myField` has the distinct values: `[1, 15, 151, 21, 22]`, and `term` is `1`, then I'd expect to get from ES the buckets with keys `[1, 15, 151]`.

The problem is this does not seem to work with numeric fields. For the above example, I am getting a single bucket with the key `1`, and if `term` is `15` I am getting a single bucket with key `15`, i.e. it only returns exact matches. In contrast, it works perfectly for `string` typed fields.

I am guessing I need some special mapping for `myField`, but I'd prefer to have the mapping as general as possible, while having the autocomplete working with minimal changes to the mapping (just to note - the index I am querying might be a general one, external to my application, so I will be able to change the type/field mappings in it only if the new mapping is something general and standard).

What are my options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is to create a `string` sub-field into your integer field, like this:

```
{
    "myField": {
        "type": "integer",
        "fields": {
            "to_string": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your query would need to be changed to the one below, i.e. query on the string field, but retrieve the terms aggregations from the integer field

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "myField.to_string": "1"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "myAggregation": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myField",
        "size": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you can also create a completely independent field, not necessary a sub-field, the key point is that one field needs the integer value to run the `terms` aggregation on and the other field needs the string value to run the `prefix` query on.

Comment: After adding the `to_string` sub-field to the mapping, would I need to reindex the data? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to re-index your data otherwise the sub-field is not populated.